# How to implement hierarchy faceted search in Elasticsearch with aggregations

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I'm working on a standard ecommerce application which has Products with many to many Categories.

Categories are Trees and stored in Nested Set form in the database.

Categories can have subcategories and so on.

I want to use Elasticsearch for search functionality, but I can't find any use case (or sample) for such standard (almost all webshops has that functionality) faceted search that I will try to explain below:

### Categories

#### table:

```
----------------------------------------------
|id      | name        | lft     | rgt       |
----------------------------------------------
|1       | Electronics | 1       | 18        |
|2       | Accesories  | 2       | 9         |
|3       | Cards       | 3       | 4         |
|4       | Stations    | 5       | 6         |
|5       | Cables      | 7       | 8         |
|6       | Computers   | 10      | 15        |
|7       | Laptops     | 11      | 12        |
|8       | Software    | 13      | 14        |
|9       | Phones      | 16      | 17        |
|10      | House       | 19      | 20        |
```

#### visualy:

```
Electronics
    Accesories
        Cards
        Stations
        Cables
    Computers
        Laptops
        Software
    Phones
House
```

### Products

```
---------------------------
|id      | name           |
---------------------------
|1       | Lenovo G580    |
|2       | Iphone 5       |
|3       | Keyboard       |
|4       | Mouse          |
|5       | Sony Xperia Z5 |
```

### Products and Categories

```
---------------------------
|product_id  | category_id |
----------------------------
| 1          | 1           |
| 1          | 6           |
| 1          | 7           |
| 2          | 1           |
| 2          | 9           |
| 3          | 1           |
| 3          | 2           |
| 4          | 1           |
| 4          | 2           |
| 5          | 1           |
| 5          | 9           |
```

### What I want to do

#### Case 1

Assume that in this case there is no category selected and the search box input is empty.
I want to display distinct products which belongs to all root categories with counts of it in all that categories. Somethink like that:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| ------------------------------------                          |
| | type for searching...            |                          |
| ------------------------------------                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Categories       | Products                                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Electronics (5)  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Lenovo G580                             |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Iphone 5                                |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Keyboard                                |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Mouse                                   |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Sony Xperia Z5                          |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
```

Please note that there is no House category on the left becasue it doesn't have products.

#### Case 2

Assume that in this case there is a  category selected and the search box input is empty again.

And there is a key point for me:

If user select category (Electronics in this case) I want to display one level of it's subcategories with count of products which belongs to their with link to parents category. Somethink like that:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| ------------------------------------                          |
| | type for searching...            |                          |
| ------------------------------------                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Categories       | Products                                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| ^--              | |-------------------------------------------
| Accesories (2)   | |  Lenovo G580                             |
| Computers (1)    | |-------------------------------------------
| Phones (2)       | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Iphone 5                                |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Keyboard                                |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Mouse                                   |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Sony Xperia Z5                          |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
```

#### Case 3

If user select last category level (like Phone below) I want to show only that level and only that products

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| ------------------------------------                          |
| | type for searching...            |                          |
| ------------------------------------                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Categories       | Products                                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| ^--              | |-------------------------------------------
| Phones (2)       | |  Iphone 5                                |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
|                  | |  Sony Xperia Z5                          |
|                  | |-------------------------------------------
```

#### Case 4

If user type somethink in the search box (but no select any of category)  I want to display all products with match search criteria and all of unique categories (no matter in which level) which does match that products.

Sorry for that very long question, but I hope it explain what I mean.

### Question

How to achieve that standard way with Elasticsearch?

### Research

SearchKit http://demo.searchkit.co/ works in that way with its http://docs.searchkit.co/stable/docs/components/navigation/hierarchical-menu.html, but I can't figure out how mapping and queries should be implemented for achieve such case...

Comment: You want to look at _faceted searching_.

Comment: I know, but all faceted search examples on the net has "flat" categories... but I need a way to deal with it like tree...

Comment: Have you finalized and figured out how to achieve this? I'm interested in learning how you handled the mappings, type of queries and the use cases you ended up with. Thanks!